Importing Data based on Column Headers
I have a workbook that has a built in button to import data from other workbooks.  The issue is that the column headers frequently change based on the report.  I have built this code to account for dynamic importing, so it imports based on column header and not column letter (which it did previosly).  For the most part it works, the only issue is that it is missing some columns.
I suspect this is due to the order it searches.  So columns C & D are not filled in because in the source document that is uploaded, that data is actually in column BF & BH.  By the time it gets that far it has already pasted data through column AZ which is where my column headers end in the target workbook.  So I feel that the code isnt cycling back and filling in columns C & D as the code has finished executing.
Honestly, dont even know if thats whats wrong, thats just my best guess.  Please see code below and advise.  Thanks!
Sub import2()

Dim OpenFileName As String
Dim wb As Workbook
'Select and Open workbook
OpenFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("clients saved spreadsheet,*.xlsx")
If OpenFileName = "False" Then Exit Sub
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(OpenFileName)



    Dim CurrentWS As Worksheet

    Dim SourceHeaderRow As Integer: SourceHeaderRow = 1
    Dim SourceCell As Range

    Dim TargetWS1 As Worksheet
    Set TargetWS1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2)
    Dim TargetHeader As Range
    Set TargetHeader = TargetWS1.Range("A1:CZ1")

    Dim RealLastRow As Long
    Dim SourceCol As Integer

    wb.Activate
    For Each Cell In TargetHeader
        If Cell.Value <> "" Then
            Set SourceCell = Rows(SourceHeaderRow).Find _
                (Cell.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
            If Not SourceCell Is Nothing Then
                SourceCol = SourceCell.Column
                RealLastRow = Columns(SourceCol).Find("*", LookIn:=xlValues, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
                If RealLastRow > SourceHeaderRow Then
                    Range(Cells(SourceHeaderRow + 1, SourceCol), Cells(RealLastRow, _
                        SourceCol)).Copy
                    TargetWS1.Cells(2, Cell.Column).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next

End Sub


It is a little hard for me to figure out exactly what you are doing, but have you checked to ensure that the headers of the missing columns are exact character for character matches for an entry in TargetHeader?  Also, why are you using wb.Activate? Activate and/or Select are rarely necessary. It might be simpler to do this in Power Query by reading in the entire table and then just rearranging the columns into your desired order.
